# Таймер на Python, с возможностью его обнуления

Tags: python, таймер

Как реализовать таймер, который можно было бы сбросить до нулевых значений. Т.е. у нас есть код, который начинает отсчет таймера, и цикл с условиями, в случае которых они бы сбрасывались.
Пример программного кода ниже:

```
timer1 = time.monotonic()
timer2 = time.monotonic()
timer3 = time.monotonic()
while True:
    LEFTANDPRESSBUTTON(0x45, 12)
    time.sleep(8)
    if timer1 > 30:
        LEFTANDPRESSBUTTON(0x45, 12)
        print('Клавиша E', timer1)
        timer1 = time.monotonic()
    else:
        break
    if timer2 > 60:
        LEFTANDPRESSBUTTON(0x45, 12)
        print('Клавиша e', timer2)
        timer2 = time.monotonic()
    else:
        break
    if timer3 > 120:
        LEFTANDPRESSBUTTON(0x45, 12)
        print('Клавиша У', timer3)
        timer3 = time.monotonic()
    else:
        break
```

Возможно логика программного кода не совсем верная, но это пока то что мне пришло в голову.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно реализовать простейший класс `Timer` для подобных целей, пример реализации и использования ниже:

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##jZDBasMwDEDv/gpBD7EhC07HGBQ62H5h3dl4rbKYOk6wFcq@PrPjtcvIDhPYSEZ6T3j4pLZ399N0tDoEOJgO/Y5BDNMNvSeg@DLXJ2xAKeMMKcUD2kbkvhSprAJpT1zcmnP9VyfBPpuqRJ@vxZxSR23tWuKRRu/Wg3D3TWVsA29BfyBb7k6yBKrj2V6tXJSrhF1aYxEOfsRsnAXBIg5cVrIWsIHXvkO49P6c/6cBktH@tAdZPfysOXjjiBfPRQnoTtFZxKyxY2iTP/LFrZXkr09LxPpKfFwjX/6DrFfIbUYueO8e9ZlN0xc)

```
class Timer:
    import time
    def __init__(self):
        self.start()
    def start(self):
        self.t = Timer.time.time()
    def __call__(self):
        return Timer.time.time() - self.t

# Usage
import time
t0, t1, t2 = Timer(), Timer(), Timer()
while True:
    time.sleep(0.01) # Some work
    if t0() >= 0.5:
        print('A', end = '', flush = True)
        t0.start()
    if t1() >= 0.75:
        print('B', end = '', flush = True)
        t1.start()
    if t2() >= 5:
        break
```

Вывод:

```
ABABAABABAABABA
```

Comment: Не нужно делать импорты внутри функций.

Comment: @insolor А в чём проблема? Я проверял, что импорт модуля просто делает проверку вначале вида `if mod_name in mod_dict: return mod_dict[mod_name]` и всё, т.е. повторный импорт мгновенный, я даже тайминги замерял, он действительно мгновенный. Точно будет быстрее чем выполнение функции `time.time()`.

Comment: @insolor Встречный вопрос, как иначе внутри класса сделать импорт модуля, который будет использоваться внутри методов класса? Так чтобы код класса был полным кодом сам в себе, т.е. чтобы не надо было перед началом класса ещё писать строку `import time`.

Comment: Проблема в том, что во-первых это в частности не соответствует рекомендациям pep8, и во-вторых не понятно зачем два раза делать импорт в каждом методе, если можно сделать это один раз в начале модуля.

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Просто делайте import time один раз в начале модуля.

Comment: @insolor Цель была в том, чтобы код класса был полным сам в себе, т.е. self-contained, т.е. чтобы просто код класса (исходный код) скопировал к себе и ничего кроме и работает всё сразу. Т.е. чтобы не надо было ещё к коду класса думать и прилагать доп модули. В этом цель. Т.е. мой вопрос в том, что если у нас задача написать некий класс так, чтобы юзеры могли копировать код только класса и ничего кроме и всё работало, как в этом случае сделать по правильному импорт? В любом случае я уже нашёл решение, сейчас поправлю ответ.

Comment: Это какая-то странная цель. Я так понимаю, вы хотите, чтобы класс можно было просто "копипастить" - так делать не нужно. Ну и не нужно приучать других к этому. Если в вашем примере нужны импорты, просто напишите их выше класса. Правильно импорт делать в самом верху модуля.

Comment: @insolor Да, именно, я хотел чтобы класс можно было "копипастить", на стэковерфлоу очень много таких небольших решений, что всё решение это одна функция или класс, приятно когда его можно себе скопипастить и больше ничего не делать и не добавлять ничего кроме в свой модуль. Т.е. полноценное в себе решение законченное получается. Но в любом случае спасибо за PEP8 рекомендацию.

Comment: `Да, именно, я хотел чтобы класс можно было "копипастить", на стэковерфлоу очень много таких небольших решений,` - вот так и начинается "stackoverflow-ориентированное программирование".